# Сбой загрузки; не отрабатывает участок кода

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, асинхронность

```
'use strict';

const NpmApi = require('npm-api');
const https  = require('https');
const fs     = require('fs');
const uuid   = require('uuid');

async function getPackageList(){
  const fname = uuid.v4();
  const PACKAGE_LIST_PATH = `/tmp/npm-choice-${fname}.txt`;
  const options = {
    'host'     : 'replicate.npmjs.com',
    'keepAlive': true,
    'path'     : '/_all_docs',
    'method'   : 'GET'
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      if(res.statusCode != 200) reject(res.statusText);

      let counter = 0;
      let headers = JSON.stringify(res.headers, ' ', 2);
      console.debug(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
      console.debug(`headers: ${headers}`);
      console.debug(`store data at ${PACKAGE_LIST_PATH}`);
      res.on('data', (data) => {
        fs.appendFile(PACKAGE_LIST_PATH, data, (err) => {
          if (err) console.log(`at getPackageList: ${err}`)
            else{
              counter++;
              process.stdout.write(`\rLoading ${counter} notes`);
            }
        });
      });
    }).end();

    req.on('error', (error) => { reject(error); });
    req.on('end', () => { resolve('######All done!'); });
  });
}

async function main(){
  let res = await getPackageList();
  console.debug(`\n\n${res}`);
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Результат:

```
statusCode: 200
headers: {
  "date": "Wed, 27 Oct 2021 05:17:35 GMT",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "connection": "close",
  "cache-control": "must-revalidate",
  "x-couch-request-id": "undefined",
  "x-couchdb-body-time": "0",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=2592000000; includeSubDomains; preload;",
  "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
  "cf-cache-status": "DYNAMIC",
  "expect-ct": "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"",
  "server": "cloudflare",
  "cf-ray": "6a497574af604991-DME"
}
store data at /tmp/npm-choice-7eebfb96-0a72-4bad-b819-adebedc8bee6.txt
Loading 4808 notes
```

Проблемы:

1. загрузка не завершается: `Loading 4808 notes` висит неограниченное количество времени при том, что ошибок сетевого подключения не выводится. Случается не всегда. Количество загруженных записей до повисания каждый раз варьируется. Как восстановить загрузку в таком случае?
2. участки кода `req.on('end', () => { resolve('######All done!'); });` и `` console.debug(`\n\n${res}`); `` не отрабатывают даже в тех редких случаях, когда загрузка доходит до конца. Что я делаю не так?

Буду рад любой помощи, поскольку решений в сети найти не смог. Видимо у всех нормальных людей сеть мегастабильная и восстановление подключения не требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req` это [ClientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest), у него нет события `end`.

Вам нужно слушать событие `end` у ответа `res`.

```js
res.on('end', () => { resolve('######All done!'); });
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос можно считать закрытым. Кроме описанного Вами, я выяснил, что у ```https.request``` по какой-то причине нет опции ```timeout```. А выяснилось, когда заменил ```https.request``` на ```wget```. При стандартном таймауте 2 с происходит ```SOCKETTIMEOUTERROR```. ```wget``` об этом говорит, а этот вот... почему-то нет.